# JSON Parsing showing NullPointerException in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Hi I have a JSON Data and I'm getting it through url by using get method,I need to show the sender,receiver,message in Textview,I have created a JsonParser class also but after running the app its showing  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.How to fix this issue.

Here is what I have tried

```
private static String url = "http://130.211.99.188/api/messages";
JSONArray _items = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    if (Utils.isNetConnected(this))
    {

        new Parser().execute();

    }

    else
        Utils.showDialog(this);
}


class Parser extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONData(url);
        try{
                    _items = json.getJSONArray("_updated");
                    for(int i=0;i<_items.length();i++){
                                JSONObject object = _items.getJSONObject(i);

                                sender = object.getString("sender");
                                receiver = object.getString("receiver");
                                message = object.getString("message");

                    }
        }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
       }//Ending doInBackground


                    @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                                super.onPostExecute(result);
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                t1.setText(sender);
                                t2.setText(receiver);
                                t3.setText(message);

                    }
    }

}
```

This is my JSON Data

```
 {"_items": [{"_updated": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", "sender":          "556a1233aca33b3c8158de0a", "timestamp": 1433018976, "receiver": "5569c6c5aca33b3c8158de07", "_links": {"self": {"href": "messages/556a2260aca33b3c8158de11", "title": "messages"}}, "message_created": "Sat, 30 May 2015 20:49:36 GMT", "seen": false, "message": "hii", "_id": "556a2260aca33b3c8158de11", "_etag": "afa4fe57efec9abf7c5bc817a7e045a5b4467384", "_created": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"},
```

Comment: This JSON response message is complex. I would recommend you using Jackson JSON parser to process it.

Comment: I have checked the reponse, _updated is an object not an array.

Comment: "_updated":"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", _updated is a String TIMESTAMP NOT An array

Comment: @Aakash can you please edit the code and correct it ?

Comment: Show us the Json structure

Comment: @Lennon just edited the ques please cheeck it.

Comment: Instead of this   _items = json.getJSONArray("_updated");  ,use this 

  _items = json.getJSONArray("_items");

Comment: Also to avoid null pointer exception, you should use json.has("YOUR_KEY");  This will return true or false and you can handle null pointer exception. Wait i update you with the code.

Comment: @Aakash tried but not working.not getting why its happenning struggling from hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete code, have a look at the data printed

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog pdialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new postServer().execute();
    }
    public String postData() throws JSONException {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        String downloadedString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // for registerhttps://te
//          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://130.211.99.188/api/messages");
            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


//          HttpPost myConnection = new HttpGet("http://130.211.99.188/api/messages");

            try {
//              HttpResponse  response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://130.211.99.188/api/messages"));
                downloadedString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("downloadedString:in login:::"
                    + downloadedString);

        return downloadedString;
    }

    public class postServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String jsonstring = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pdialog.setCancelable(false);
            pdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pdialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pdialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                jsonstring = postData();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                if(pdialog!=null){
                    pdialog.dismiss();
                }
                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
                JSONArray array=mainObject.getJSONArray("_items");
                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("sender"));
                    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("receiver"));
                    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("message"));
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                if (pdialog != null) {
                    pdialog.dismiss();
                }
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry aakash its not printing anything its empty

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just declaring the JSONArray variable without assigning it a null value? `JSONArray _items;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 _items = json.getJSONArray("_updated");
```

Change to

```
  _items = json.getJSONArray("_items");
```

And

```
 class Parser extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {
```

to

```
 class Parser extends AsyncTask < void, void, void > {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class Parser extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {


    protected void onPreExecute() {     
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONData(url);

        try{

            _items = json.getJSONArray("_items");

            for(int i=0; i<_items.length(); i++){

                JSONObject object = _items.getJSONObject(i);

                sender = object.optString("sender");
                receiver = object.optString("receiver");
                message = object.optString("message");

            }

        }
        catch(JSONException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return message;

   }


    @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pDialog.dismiss();

        t1.setText(sender);
        t2.setText(receiver);
        t3.setText(message);

    }

}
```

Try to use `optString()` instead of `getString()` because the former returns `null` if doesn't exist and it doesn't throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `getJSONData(url)` in `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONData(url);` is not returning null?

Your question indicates that you are calling getJSONArray() on a null object. Which means the JSON object you queried from the parser is null